# Adobe Creative SDK integration Android error

Tags: android, sdk, adobe

Following the given documentation: https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html
I proceeded with my project setup but when I go on to edit the build.gradle file for my app and add the  compile project(':creativesdk:CreativeSDKImage') dependency and rebuild, the build fails showing the Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Here is my settings.gradle file-

```
include ':app'
include ':creativesdk'
include ':creativesdk:CreativeSDKImage'
include ':creativesdk:Foundation:CreativeSDKFoundationAuth'
project(':creativesdk').projectDir = new File
     ("C:\\Users\\Neel Raj\\Desktop\\AdobeTest\\creativesdk-repo\\com\\adobe/creativesdk")
project(':creativesdk:CreativeSDKImage').projectDir = new File
    ("C:\\Users\\Neel Raj\\Desktop\\AdobeTest\\creativesdk-repo\\com\\adobe/creativesdk/CreativeSDKImage")
project(':creativesdk:Foundation:CreativeSDKFoundationAuth').projectDir = new File
    ("C:\\Users\\Neel Raj\\Desktop\\AdobeTest\\creativesdk-repo\\com\\adobe/creativesdk/Foundation/CreativeSDKFoundationAuth")
```

The build.gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.neelraj.adobetest"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile project(':creativesdk:CreativeSDKImage')
}
```

I cannot figure out a way to fix this. I'm not even sure if I'm doing everything correctly. But I have followed the documentation step by step.

Any detailed way to setup the image sdk would be very helpful

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28293606/1188978

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with this guide.
Just see here : [Trying to make an Android Studio Application with Adobe Creative SDK Image Editing, cannot get libraries compiled in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532920/trying-to-make-an-android-studio-application-with-adobe-creative-sdk-image-editi)
Follow the steps to configure the SDK.

After that you can follow the rest of the mentioned tutorial.
What helped me was to look at the sample code from Android Creative SDK "CreativeSDKImageSampleApp" and after some hours it worked for me

Comment: I saw that solution earlier but the problem is that I need to edit the aviary editor xml files but I couldn't find them anyhere in the sample app implementation

Comment: Mh? "Edit the aviary editor xml files" is a new problem or is it related to your question, how to setup.

Comment: It is related because when I did what you said in the reply, the setup is quite similar to the sample app, and it invikes the default aviary editor. However the documentation says that I can edit the editor layout by editing the aviary styles.xml files but I couldn't find them in the sample app

Comment: Ah. Yeah. I wanted to edit the xml files too.
Unfortunatelyand I couldnt find them either. How you said, they aren't at the sdk or samples.
If you find sth about it, would be nice if you share it with me.

Comment: Hey there. Long time gone.
I looked today into the Getting started page and saw that they gave more informationen into the customization. 
See https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html under point 11.
Just in case you didnt noticed it.
Btw. I didnt tried it yet. But this is probably solid.