# Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0 when trying to set up Adobe creative SDK

Tags: android, aviary

So I feel like I've exhausted all options to try and get this to work and is driving me f***** crazy.

I'm trying to implement the adobe creative SDK. I have followed [this tutorial](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html) very attentively but it's still not working.

All I get when clicking sync with grade etc is the following error:

```
Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Here's my build.grade file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo"  //ADD THE CORRECT LOCATION OF THE CREATIVESDK LIBRARY FILES
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "editor.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-  INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'

}
```

[image]

If anyone can help, it will save my sanity.

Also, I've looked at the following questions and they didn't work either:

[Trying to make an Android Studio Application with Adobe Creative SDK Image Editing, cannot get libraries compiled in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532920/trying-to-make-an-android-studio-application-with-adobe-creative-sdk-image-editi)

[Android Studio Error when adding Adobe Creative SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261118/android-studio-error-when-adding-adobe-creative-sdk)

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. The documentation is wrong.

The line should be:

```
maven {
    url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release"
}
```

Comment: I think someone should contact them if their documentation is incorrct, that's very annoying and wastes soo many people's time.

Answer (score 2):

The newest Android SDK is no longer downloadable. Instead, you need to change the URL to:

```
        url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
```

Check Adobe documentation for more details.

Comment: Strange: I have download the sample, and it had: url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release"
} line.

Comment: @itzo I am still facing issue to load lib can you pleae help me ?